# Why is QAudioRecorder not recording through the constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

**header**

```
#ifndef AUDIORECORD_H
#define AUDIORECORD_H

#include <QMediaRecorder>
#include <QAudioRecorder>
#include <QUrl>

class AudioRecorder : public QAudioRecorder
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AudioRecorder(QObject * parent);
    ~AudioRecorder(){}

};

#endif // AUDIORECORD_H
```

**source**

```
#include "audiorecord.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
AudioRecorder::AudioRecorder(QObject * parent = 0)
{
    this->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.mp3"));

    int x = 0;
    while ( x > 10000)
    {
        this->record();
        x++;
    }

    this->stop();

    std::cout<<"\ndsffsdf\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "audiorecord.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QObject p;
    AudioRecorder obj(&p);
    
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

This does not produce any error but it does not record also. I am not expecting any quality or full fledged recording.

I just want to see how this recorder works.

That test.mp3 is not getting saved.
What bare minimum can I add or subtract to it to make it record something and save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause

What would be if I tell you 10 000 times: *Go buy some milk*, while firmly holding your hand, then just before I let you go to say: *Ah, forget it*? Would you be able to buy the milk?

You are doing the same with your code:

```
int x = 0;
while ( x > 10000)
{
    this->record();
    x++;
}

this->stop();
```

You are calling 10 000 times `QAudioRecorder::record`, but you do not let Qt get to the event loop and actualy execute your command. Then just before Qt gets to the event loop, you say: `stop`.

### Solution

First of all, you do not need to subclass `QAudioRecorder`, because you do not add any new functionality to it. Just create an instance of the class and use it.

Second, `record` and `stop` are slots. Connect them to the `clicked` signal of the corresponding push buttons in you GUI, e.g.:

```
auto *audioRecorder = new QAudioRecorder(this);

...

connect(btnRecord, &QPushButton::clicked, audioRecorder, &QAudioRecorder::record);
connect(btnStop, &QPushButton::clicked, audioRecorder, &QAudioRecorder::stop);
```

**Note:** For more information, please take a look at the example from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiorecorder.html#details).